# How to delete primary business profile in twilio

Tags: twilio

I accidently entered the wrong business for the primary business profile, it's already approved. I don't see any way to delete it. Does anyone know how I can change it? I'm working through the A2P compliance and need help. thanks.

Tried looking for a way to delete the info and resubmit it but not finding any help in support docs

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix this is by [reaching out to support](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048500694-Contacting-Twilio-Support).